# Loop over two associative arrays in Bash

Tags: bash, associative-array

Say I have two associative arrays in Bash

```
declare -A a
declare -A b
a[xz]=1
b[xz]=2
a[zx]=3
b[zx]=4
```

I want to do something like this

```
for arr in ${a[@]} ${b[@]}; do echo ${arr[zx]}; done
```

and get 3 and 4 in output

but I get

```
$ for arr in ${a[@]} ${b[@]}; do echo ${arr[zx]}; done
1
3
2
4
```

Is there a way to do this in Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to iterate over the contents; you want to iterate over the *names* of the arrays, then use indirect expansion to get the desired value of the fixed key from each array.

```
for arr in a b; do
    t=$arr[zx]   # first a[zx], then b[zx]
    printf '%s\n' "${!t}"
done
```

Here, the variable "name" for use in indirect expansion is the name of the array along with the desired index.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly I was looking for, but is it working?


    $ for arr in a b; do t=arr[zx]; printf '%s\n' "${!t}"; done
    a
    b

Comment: It does work, if you fix my dumb mistake (`arr` needs to be expanded when setting `t`).

Comment: @chepner : May be am missing a point here, but for the other indices like xz?

Comment: @Inian The question only asks for output from a (variable) set of arrays using a fixed key.

Comment: @AndreyRomanchev No, `t=$arr[zx]`. You aren't indexing an array yet; you just want a string that consists of the array name (`$arr` expanding to `a` or `b`, depending on which iteration you are on) followed by the fixed string `[zx]`. Now that `t` is either `a[zx]` or `b[zx]`, you use indirect expansion of `t` to get the desired array element.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* the keys in both the arrays match(a major assumption), you can use one array as reference and loop over the keys and print in each array.

```
for key in "${!a[@]}"; do 
    printf "Array-1(%s) %s Array-2(%s) %s\n" "$key" "${a[$key]}" "$key" "${b[$key]}"
done
```

which produces an output as below. You can of-course remove the fancy debug words(`Array-1`, `Array-2`) which was added just for an understanding purpose.

```
Array-1(xz) 1 Array-2(xz) 2
Array-1(zx) 3 Array-2(zx) 4
```

One general good practice is *always* quote (`for key in "${!a[@]}"`) your array expansions in `bash`, so that the elements are not subjected to word-splitting by the shell.